# Laravel Validator. Unable to retrieve both errors and Input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

I am using Laravel for a project and i am trying to validate some input fields from a form. I am using the Validator class.

Here is the code in my controller.

```
$validator =   Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'arithmos_kinhths' => 'required',
    'kathgoria_kinhths' => ['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
    'prohgoumenos_paroxos_kinhths' => ['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
    'programma_kinhths' => ['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
    'project_kinhths' => ['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
    'kathogoria_epidothshs_kinhths' =>['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
    'talk_to_eu_kinhths' => ['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
    'pagio_kinhths' => 'required',
    'sms_kinhths' => ['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
    'internet_kinhths' => ['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
   'international_kinhths' => ['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
    'twin_sim_kinhths' => ['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
    'wind_unlimited_kinhths' => ['required',Rule::notIn(['-'])],
]);


if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

In the blade file i am trying to catch the errors using the code bellow.

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <script>
        $.notify(
            {
                title: '<strong>ERROR!</strong>',
                message: '{{$error}}',
            },
            {
                type: 'danger',
            },
        )
    </script>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Also i want to put the old values into the input fields using `{{old('value'}}`

The problem i have is that i can't combine both errors and inputs. If i return only the errors using `withErrors($validator)` the errors are printed out. And if i return only withInput i have the post values.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use $this->validateWith([]), put your validation here you don't need to redirect back to your page, it will redirect of the page from where that request happend.

Comment: Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests; this is already extended by your app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php file. you just need to use it

Comment: I tried it. By using this, i don't get neither errors or old post values...

Answer (score 0):

```
withInputs()
```

try this, i hope that help a little , or 
you can

```
return back()->with('errors',$validator)->withInputs()
```

Comment: It is not working. By using withInputs() it gives me undefined offset 0. Also in documentation the function withInput() is used

Answer (score 0):

you can use $this->validatorWith([]) then follow your code, you don't need to manually redirect back to that page. your request will auto redirect to that page from where request has happened. this function belongs to trait Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests which is use by app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php. you just need to use. for more about this trait see here [ValidateRequest](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.html)

```
$this->validatorWith([
    'request_param' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: Nope. I tried both validateWith(), and validate() functions with no success. Only with Validator class i got the messages but i faced the problem i described on the post...

Comment: <input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email" value="{{old('name')}}">
              @if($errors->has("email"))
                <span>{{$errors->first('email')}}</span>

              @endif

Comment: Our codes are identical. This is what i am using also and worked everytime.           if ($errors->has('paroxos_statheris'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong style="color: red;">{{ $errors->first('paroxos_statheris') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif

Comment: https://github.com/uditrawat03/laravel-vue/blob/dev-10/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php

https://github.com/uditrawat03/laravel-vue/blob/dev-10/resources/views/manage/users/create.blade.php

Comment: I have shared some of my code from github repo, hope this will help you.